# onBindViewHolder or VievHolder couldn't show another xml

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

hi i am trying use recyclerview. I have two layout one of them mainactivity which has cardview and recyclerview and other one is feeditem xml this one has hold item requirements for show in recyclerview(name,feed,date). But i guess i might have problem  onBindViewHolder or VievHolder  because i just see mainactivity i cant show anything in recyclerview and the tools inside the feeditem xml actually i can't bind each other.

**MainActivity**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView = this.findViewById(R.id.rv_f2);
        // recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        databaseReference = database.getReference("allfeed");
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<feedmember> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<feedmember>().setQuery(databaseReference, feedmember.class).build();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<feedmember, VievHolder_feed> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<feedmember, VievHolder_feed>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VievHolder_feed holder, int position, @NonNull feedmember model)
            { holder.setitem(this , model.getName(), model.getFeed(), model.getTime()); }
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public VievHolder_feed onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.feed_item, parent, false);
                return new VievHolder_feed(view); }};
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter); }}
```

**Viewholder_feed**

```
 public class VievHolder_feed extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView time_result,name_result,que_result;
        public VievHolder_feed(@NonNull View itemView) { super(itemView); }
        public void setitem(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<feedmember, VievHolder_feed> activity, String name, String time, String feed){
            time_result =itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_que_item);
            name_result =itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_que_item_tv);
            que_result =itemView.findViewById(R.id.que_item_tv);
            time_result.setText(time);
            name_result.setText(   name);
            que_result.setText(feed); }}
```

[[image]]

Comment: What does `model.getName()` return?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your recycler view received the item, but the view holder binds the fields with blank contents.

Did you verify if the mapping inside `feedmember` class works fine ?

Comment: i changed somethings now i get one more error that is "DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type feedmember" but when i write text to textview in feedıtem.xml file it doesn't show.

Comment: Referring to the "FirebaseRecyclerAdapter" implementation, the startListening must be called inside the "onStart" callback in your activity.

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java